# DTD If the value is something other than X then show

Tags: xml, dtd

I am creating a DTD and in my DTD if I have a default value, let's call it "home". If this is the value then the element should not be shown, however if it is anything else I need to show it. Ie. if it is "work" or "mobile" for example.

How would I do that?

So far I have specified it as:

```
    <!ELEMENT location (#PCDATA>
    <!ATTLIST location type (Home | Work | Mobile) #REQUIRED>
```

I have no idea how to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be specified in the DTD.

This sounds like it should be handled by the application consuming the XML. The application would determine whether or not `location` is shown based on the attribute value.

If you truly don't want the `location` element to exist in the data itself, make it optional in whatever models allow it and remove `Home` from the `type` attribute enumeration.